# User's computer does not render mathjax

Tags: support, mathjax, specific-question

I was trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472789/what-are-the-steps-required-to-solve-this-system-of-equations/472802?noredirect=1#comment1018039_472802), and it seems that the asker can't view mathjax.  I have no idea how to troubleshoot this kind of issue, so some help here would be much appreciated.

Any ideas as to what exactly is going wrong?

**EDIT:**  I was able to come up with a workaround for the particular question, but for future-reference, I'd like to know what went wrong if possible

Comment: What was the workaround? That might give us a hint as to what was going on.

Comment: @robjohn I uploaded a screenshot of the rendered mathjax. So image-viewing wasn't affected

Comment: @robjohn thank you for showing me the ways of your TeX-fU

Comment: I just reformatted so things lined up a bit more pleasingly. I don't think it will help the OP. Another idea would be to use the `array` environment (since it is representing an array).

Comment: Good idea, I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: If the post can be viewed without problems, wouldn't ([meta-tag:support]) be a more appropriate tag than ([meta-tag:bug])?

Comment: I've added the [tag:mathjax] tag (which got converted to a [tag:tex] tag) to attract the MathJax gods. I have no clue what might be wrong with the user's computer. It could be trouble communicating with the MathJax server.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: good point.

Comment: There are so many things that can have gone wrong. (1) The user may be behind a firewall that aggressively blocked the MathJAX CDN. (2) The user may have javascript turned off. (3) The user may have a really slow computer and/or running an old broswer so it just takes _realllly_ long to process MathJAX. And there are more reasons that MathJAX may fail. Random guessing is unlikely to help.

Comment: In general I will suggest (a) first finding out the user's browser and operating system versions and (b) direct them to the [MathJAX samples page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/) to see if the problem is only on Math.SE. If the user is capable of doing it, guide them through (c) using the javascript console (if the user uses Chrome/Firefox/some browser where such trouble shooting tool is included) and see what the errors are.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for the helpful comments. It's good to have some sort of protocol for how to deal with these situations, and these checks seem like a good place to start.

Comment: A dedicated chatroom may be useful for following up on Willie's suggestions.